# Changes to PHP take too long to reload

Tags: php, linux, server

Whenever I make a change to a php file and I upload it to the server it takes too long(about 30-60 seconds) for the server to send to my browser the updated version.
I have tried clearing the browser cache but it doesn't change anything it seems to be a server issue. Is there anyway to fix this for as long as I develop my site?

Comment: server probably caches PHP. it's definitly a server issue. why do not devlop locally in the first place?!

Comment: Can you explain how are you deploying your code. Are you implementing any caching techniques like (varnish / memcache)

Comment: @PhilippSander it's not my choice, it's the company's choice.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki no as far as I know, I upload my .php files using ftp after I edit them and the run them from the browser

Comment: Which hosting service provider are you using. Have you tried to contacting them. May be they use APC for performance.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki the webserver is hosted on Microsoft Azure and we use a lamp version on Ubuntu 14. I have complete access to the server configuration so if there is a suggested answer I can implement it.

Comment: Get them to remove the cacheing while you are developing

Comment: you have a lamp-stack and you're not allowed to use it?! your companies choice is bullshit.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you tell me how to do It myself? I am allowed to.

Comment: No sorry. I dont know which cache you are using or anything about your server

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is the default latest version of apache2 almost zero configuration done.

Comment: kick the tires, shake the system ... after a deployment try to `service apache2 restart` ... and `service php5-fpm restart`  (if you use it) ... and see if there is a difference in behavior.  That could help you isolate the issue.  If you are using a bloated framework, it could be using a memcache(type) ... which could also explain the delays.  Restart that too, isolate the cause.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg apache2 restart seems to do the trick, but i would prefer not to do that everytime

Comment: @Kostas as would I.  I have three stacks (dev, staging, prod) and mostly work on dev.  When deploying to staging or prod, the restart is parte of the deployment script, and it is upon rare occasions. Restarting on dev is a cinch and ultra fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer is to restart the apache server:

> service apache2 restart

another that also seems to work is to add this line to your .htaccess file:

> Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"